# linq to ienumerable where child ienumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

How could I select parking with id 1 and only the cars of year 200 in that park

```
var List<Parking> cityParkings = new List<Parking>
{
    new Parking{ id = 1, carsInPark = new List<Car>{ new Car{ year = 2000}, new Car{ year = 2001} }},
    new Parking{ id = 2, carsInPark = new List<Car>{ new Car{ year = 2000}, new Car{ year = 1999} }},
    new Parking{ id = 3, carsInPark = new List<Car>{ new Car{ year = 2005}, new Car{ year = 2000} }},
}
```

**expected result:**

```
Parking { id = 1, carsInPark = List<Car>{ Car{ year = 2000} } }
```

select the **existing parking instance** of id 1 with existing cars instances, but only the cars of 2000's year.

Thanks ;)

Comment: **The existing instance** is required since those are actually nhibernate models I'd like to operate on later.

Comment: well. on the other hand its pretty much impossible to "get the same one" but different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cityParkings.Where(p => p.id = 1)
   .Select(pp => new Parking(){id = pp.id, carsInPark = pp.carsInPark.Where(c=>c.year == 2000).ToList()});
```